# "docker compose" environment file pass through shell variables don't work anymore

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-desktop

I want to use an environment file (`env_file`) to pass through untouched shell variables. What's the correct syntax?

My `docker-compose.yaml` file:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  daemon:
    image: my-image
    env_file:
      - ./env/docker.development.env
    ...
```

My `env` file (used to work, but no longer works):

```
ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
```

The `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` used to be passed through from the shell variables. It doesn't work anymore.

I tried:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
```

The resulting environment variables in the container are always empty. The [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/)  seems to state that it should work.

**When doing it** from the `docker-compose.yaml` `environment` clause, then it works though, *i.e.*

```yaml
...
    image: my-image
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
```

but I want to do it from a common `env_file` to avoid repetition for all my services.

*Note*: Using Docker Desktop for Windows w/ Linux Subsystem version 4.0.1 (68347)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the [release notes](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/release-notes/#docker-desktop-401), I realized there is a new "Docker Compose V2" option.

[image: Use Docker Compose V2 checkbox]

From the [GitHub](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues), there seems to be many issues still with Compose V2 and environment variables. Unchecking the option resolves the problem.